# gulp pipe(gulp.dest()) does not create any results

Tags: javascript, gulp

i am currently learning about gulp.js.
as i saw the tutorial and documentation of gulp.js, this code:

```
gulp.src('js/*.js')
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest('minjs'));
```

makes the uglified javascript file with create new directory named 'minjs'. of course, i installed gulp-uglity with --dev-save option. there is no error message on the console so i don't know what is the problem. i tried gulp with "sudo", but still not working.

so i went to the root directory and searched all filesystem but there is no file named 'minjs' so i guess it just not working. why this is happening? anyone knows this problem, it would be nice why this is happening.

whole source code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    console.log('mifying scripts...');

    gulp.src('js/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('minjs'));
});
```

Comment: Can you try `.pipe(gulp.dest('./minjs/'));`?

Comment: it will create `minjs` folder relative to the directory containing your `gulpfile.js`. Did you check there ?

Comment: Arkantos// yep. i checked, no 'minjs' directory ;(

Comment: Manasov Daniel// just i tried, but nothing happens either.

Comment: how are you executing your gulp tasks ? You can go to the directory containing `gulpfile.js` and give `gulp` for executing default task. Do you see any errors while doing this ?

Comment: are you sure there are files under js directory or else change ur regex to `js/**/*.js`. also just change to `return gulp.src`

Comment: thank you guys, i don't know what was the problem, but it's just working now!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I showed it to a colleague, who also said it did not work, and then suddenly it started working for them. Unfortunately, it still is not working for me, and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem; you have to return the task inside the function:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
 return gulp.src("js/*.js")
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('minjs'));
```

Also, `minjs` will not be a file, but a folder, where all your minified files are going to be saved.

Finally, if you want to minify only 1 file, you can specify it directly, the same with the location of the destination.

For example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');    

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify('./src/client/app.js')
        .bundle()
        // Pass desired output filename to vinyl-source-stream
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        // Start piping stream to tasks!
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));
});

    gulp.task('build', ['browserify'], function() {
         return gulp.src("./public/main.js")
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));
    });
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved the question like this:

It was a directory mistake so the gulp task hasn't matched any files; then it couldn't create the dest directory (because no files in output).

```js
const paths = {
  dest: {
    lib: './lib',
    esm: './esm',
    dist: './dist',
  },
  styles: 'src/components/**/*.less',
  scripts: ['src/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}', '!src/components/**/demo/*.{ts,tsx}'],
};
```

At first my scripts was `['components/**/*.{ts,tsx}', '!components/**/demo/*.{ts,tsx}']`

And that hasn't matched any files.